# Are they all the same in meaning: "How far up something" OR "How far above something" OR "How far up above something"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, emphasis

**How Far Up Above The Earth's Surface Do You Need To Go Before The Gravitational Acceleration Is 1/5 Of What You Feel On The Earth's?**

The group of words that make up the question **"How far up above the earth's surface...."** has drawn my attention. Since **"up"** and **"above"** has the same meaning and both work well in this question, I didn't see a need to use them together. However, since I am a non-native speaker, I still want to make sure if I am right in my thinking that it is nothing but overuse of the similar words.

Why **"how far up above...."** whereas simply the following seem to have same meaning:

**- How far up the earth's surface .......?**

**- How far above the earth's surface .......?**

Aren't they really the same in meaning?

Comment: "[ ***up above the sky so high***..☆](https://genius.com/Chantal-kreviazuk-and-raine-maida-twinkle-twinkle-little-star-lyrics)”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

*How far up the...* can only be used of something you climb (like a mountain or a tree) or go along or through (like a street or a pipe).

Strictly speaking, it would be enough to say *How far above the Earth's surface?*, but expressions such as *up above, down below* are commonly used to add emphasis.